# Twitter/Google Fabric and Office UI Fabric

Tags: twitter-fabric, office-ui-fabric, fabric.io

Can anyone tell the relations between the Twitter (now Google) Fabric (https://get.fabric.io/) and Office UI Fabric (https://dev.office.com/fabric).

Is the Office UI Fabric built as an extension to Fabric.io or does the similarities end in the name by being totally separate code bases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here.

There isn't a connection, other then name, between Fabric (get.fabric.io) - used by mobile app developers, and Microsoft's Office UI which is a front-end framework for making UI or UX within Microsoft Office.

Comment: Note that Office Fabric (css, js) has an MIT licence so it's not limited to Office usage, only the assets: icons and fonts have special licence so they can only be used within the context of Office